# how to control accelerometer and use it in android remot controlled car

Tags: android, bluetooth, accelerometer, dtmf

i want to drive a remote controlled car using android phone.
i used Bluetooth earphone  works as receiver .
my phone sends DTMF tones  and  when its received by the earphone it's analyzed by
microcontroller   to turn on / off the car motors .

i used accelerometer to detect phone motion ... ( front / left /right / back )
and  on each movement it plays a specific DTMF tone .

it all works   but there is a problem :

the tone is played alot  as the sensors values changes continuously   !

the question : how can i make the tone played  only one time ?? ( as in the code )

here is the code :

```
 X = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x);
    Y = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y);
    Z = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z);

    toneGenerator= new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF,ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);



    sel = new SensorEventListener(){  
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }  

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {  

              float[] values = event.values; 
              float x = values[0];  
              float   xx = Math.round(x) ;
              float y = values[1]; 
              float   yy = Math.round(y) ;
              float z = values[2];  
              float   zz = Math.round(z) ;

              X.setText("x:" + xx);  

              Y.setText("y:" + yy);
              Z.setText("z:" + zz);

              if (xx>-1 & xx<1 & zz>3 & zz<8 ) {
                state.setText ("normal");

                toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_5);


                   new CountDownTimer(50, 500) { 
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { } 
                    public void onFinish() { 
                     toneGenerator.stopTone();
                  }}.start();
              }

              if (xx>-1 & xx<1 & zz>8 ) {

                state.setText ("front");

                     toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_2);
                       new CountDownTimer(50, 500) { 
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { } 
                        public void onFinish() { 
                         toneGenerator.stopTone();
                      }}.start();
```

any suggestions ???

Answer (score 0):

That is a little difficult since humans can't stand still with any part of the body for 100%.

Have you tried placing the phone on a table to see what it happens ?

Comment: But which values ? The accelerometer values or the compass values ?

Comment: the values of accelerometer ...   i get the values from them onSensorchanged (events)  .... 
i rounded them  to try to avoid the tiny changes but the sensor keeps updating the values ... and even if the values didnt change it still plays tones .

Comment: Which values to you use ? I think it would be easier using the compass, defining your "limits" and using the accelerometer to determine the speed that changes the phones position.